# Redirect from a subdirectory to the parent without symbolic links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a script in `/` and I need my site would be available from the `/m` directory as well. I can't use symbolic links, so it would be nice to do it in mod_rewrite.

I found something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

and placed it within the `/m` directory, but without any effects. There is no redirection to the root directory.

It should be done that it isn't direct redirection to the root directory, but the URL in a browser should be with the `/m` directory all the time.

Quick introduce:

```
example.com ---> / (example.com in a browser address bar) 
example.com/m ---> / (example.com/m in a browser address bar)
```

Is there any way to do it in mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

If the rules *need* to be in the htaccess file in the `/m/` directory, you may be able to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/m/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Otherwise, you can add this rule to the htaccess file in your document root (`/`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```